# Running Libreoffice BASIC macro from python

Tags: python, macros, libreoffice, basic, libreoffice-calc

I've a macro in LibreOffice BASIC and I want to run it from my python program. I've found some threads in which they use this code:

```
import os
import win32com.client

if os.path.exists("excelsheet.xlsm"):
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename="C:\Full Location\To\excelsheet.xlsm", ReadOnly=1)
    xl.Application.Run("excelsheet.xlsm!modulename.macroname")
##    xl.Application.Save() # if you want to save then uncomment this line and change delete the ", ReadOnly=1" part from the open function.
    xl.Application.Quit() # Comment this out if your excel script closes
    del xl
```

But this is for windows Excell program and I want for the LibreOffice program. Is it possible to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

My preferred way is to put the python script in the Scripts/python subfolder of your [LibreOffice user directory](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile).  Then add this function at the bottom:

```py
def call_basic_macro():
    document = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    frame = document.getCurrentController().getFrame()
    ctx = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getComponentContext()
    dispatcher = ctx.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext(
        'com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper', ctx)
    url = document.getURL()
    macro_call = ('macro:///Standard.Module1.Macro1("%s")' % url)
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(frame, macro_call, "", 0, ())

g_exported_scripts=call_basic_macro,
```

Now run the python script from Writer by going to `Tools -> Macros -> Run Macro`.  Expand `My Macros` and select the name of the script.

Another way which seems closer to your Excel example is to start a listening instance of LibreOffice with a system call:

```
start soffice -accept=socket,host=0,port=2002;urp;
```

I typically do that part in a shell script (batch file on Windows) rather than python.  Then in python, get the document context from the instance:

```
import uno
localContext = uno.getComponentContext()
```

After that, the code would look similar to what is above.  Note that with this approach on Windows, the `python.exe` included with LibreOffice must be used in order to load the `uno` module.

A third way is to simply do a system call:

```
soffice "macro:///Standard.Module1.Macro1()"
```

For more on this third approach, see https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=8232.