# Execute LibreOffice Calc Basic macro from python

Tags: python, libreoffice, uno

I am trying to automat a LibreOffice spreadsheet using Python.  I get a desktop and open the spreadsheet with

```
file_url = uno.systemPathToFileUrl(os.path.abspath("/path/to/file/estimation.xlsm"))
doc = desktop.loadComponentFromURL(file_url, "_blank", 0, oo_properties(MacroExecutionMode=4))
```

The following code will print the basic script

```
the_basic_libs = doc.BasicLibraries
the_vba = the_basic_libs.getByName("VBAProject")
the_takerate = the_vba.getByName("TakeRate")
print(the_takerate)
```

The first lines of the module printed are:

```
Rem Attribute VBA_ModuleType=VBAModule
Option VBASupport 1

Public Sub TakeRateScenarioAnalysis()
Dim StartCell As Range
```

I get the script to with

```
oor = OORunner()
msp = oor.get_context().getValueByName("/singletons/com.sun.star.script.provider.theMasterScriptProviderFactory")
sp = msp.createScriptProvider("")
scriptx = sp.getScript("vnd.sun.star.script:VBAProject.TakeRate.TakeRateScenarioAnalysis?language=Basic&location=document")
```

The following error is returned

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./runProjectEstimate.py", line 198, in <module>
    scriptx = sp.getScript("vnd.sun.star.script:VBAProject.TakeRate.TakeRateScenarioAnalysis?language=Basic&location=document")
__main__.ScriptFrameworkErrorException: The following Basic script could not be found:
library: 'VBAProject'
module: 'TakeRate'
method: 'TakeRateScenarioAnalysis'
location: 'document'
```

Is there a problem with the script URI? I don't know why I can print the script but the script provider cannot find it.

Comment: After finding the script provider factory API document I noticed that the createScriptProvider call takes a context so I changed that line to `msp.createScriptProvider(oor.get_context())` the result was the same error as before.

Comment: To make it easier to reproduce the problem, try to avoid names such as `OORunner` that are not defined in your question. In this case, it would have been better to simply write `msp = ctx.getValueByName("/singletons/com.sun.star.script.provider.theMasterScriptProviderFactory")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
scriptx = sp.getScript(
    'vnd.sun.star.script:Standard.Module1.TakeRateScenarioAnalysis?'
    'language=Basic&location=application')
```

However, as described in your question, this did not:

```
scriptx = sp.getScript(
    "vnd.sun.star.script:VBAProject.TakeRate.TakeRateScenarioAnalysis?"
    "language=Basic&location=document")
```

<strike>From these results, it does not seem possible to call macros this way when they are stored in documents. It is most likely a matter of permissions. Calling macros from documents that may have been created by someone else is a good way to spread viruses, so LO tries to prevent that.</strike>

Would it be acceptable to move your `VBAProject` library into `My Macros` instead of inside the document? Then everything should work as expected.

A couple of related links that may give more ideas:

- [How to call an existing LibreOffice python macro from a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417113/how-to-call-an-existing-libreoffice-python-macro-from-a-python-script)
- [Running Libreoffice BASIC macro from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771207/running-libreoffice-basic-macro-from-python)

**EDIT**:

There is a way to call macros stored in a document. Get the script provider **from the document**, not the master script provider.

```
oScriptProvider = doc.getScriptProvider()
oScript = oScriptProvider.getScript(
    "vnd.sun.star.script:Standard.Module1.SayHello?"
    "language=Basic&location=document")
oScript.invoke((), (), ())
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked.  I moved the script to My Macros and the automation can find the script.  I guess not running macros from the document is not just a suggestion, but enforced through the API.

Comment: One note for anyone with the same problem.  The macro I was using was created in VisualBasic in Excel.  When the macro  was in the Document the VBA compatibility allowed the script to run when called from the UI.  When I moved it to the My Macros library I could not get it to run in compatibility mode. So constructs like Frame("myNamedCell")  would cause errors. I had to convert them to sheet.getCellRangeByName("myNamedCell") as well as other VBA syntaxes.

Comment: You could set [Option Compatible](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.3/en-US/text/sbasic/shared/compatible.html). However, I would recommend rewriting the commands instead, as you have done.